# Previous exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

The code is stuck in my file although I deleted it. It still throws Previous exceptions Undefined variable: client (0)

I tried to `echo {{ $client->name }}`. There was an error so I tried to look in relations and solve the problem. Now this code `{{ $client->name }}` is stuck in my file although I deleted it. It still throws Previous exceptions Undefined variable: client (0) and I cannot resolve this. My application does not work anymore. And this is my first problem.

I tried to solve the first problem and the second problem shows. This is my Result model relations

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client');
}
```

And Client model relations

```
public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }

public function result()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Result');
  }
```

I can `echo {{$client->name}}` when listing all the clients (clients.show.blade.php), but when I try to list the client name in different file (results.create.blade.php) it throws error, undefined variable (`$client`). This is my first question about coding so if you need any more information this is the link from git hub
https://github.com/kdomagoj182/Seminar/tree/development

Comment: Did you tried clear caching in command prompt? (`php artisan cache:clear`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to copy/paste to another document and didn't work. So i tried to write the whole document from the beginning and now it's working. Any ideas on the first (original) problem?